# grafana correct way to calculate percent of request(per hour)

Tags: grafana, graphite

i know how to calculate number of successfull requests via
#A:`my.server.$Environment.api.*.httpServerRequests.exception.*.method.*.outcome.*.status.200.uri.{submit}.count`
#B:`my.server.$Environment.api.*.httpServerRequests.exception.*.method.*.outcome.*.status.200.uri.{confirm}.count`

I'm trying to count percent of confirm to submit per hour.

Will this query be correct for such purpose:

`asPecent(summarize(sumSeries(#B), '1h', 'sum', false),summarize(sumSeries(#A), '1h', 'sum', false))`

or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

summarize is not good option for such thing. I ended up using movingSum, which provides more relevant data